# How to solve such a ratio function?

Tags: matlab, math, linear-programming

Assume W is a known vector, here I want to find the unique solution a, such that:

> `Sum(min(1,W(i)/a))=M (M is known)`

Is there any specific name for such kind of function? It would be great if you guys can give me a link for some instructions.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to solve for `a` if everything else is known?

Comment: Yes, I just want to get a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the entries of W are positive; negative numbers don't make much sense in the context of your problem (since you're truncating at 1 and not at -1), while zeros contribute nothing and can be removed with `nonzeros` command.

Here's how you can solve for a:

1. Sort W from smallest to largest
2. For each i, calculate the sum that you'd get by using a = W(i).
3. Pick the largest i that still gives sum >=M. This tells you that a is between W(i) and W(i+1)
4. Increase a as needed to get sum = M. This is a matter of simple algebra because you know that the contributions of elements with index > i will be truncated to 1.

Here is an implementation. `candidates` are the various values of the sum that one gets with a=W(i), as described above.

```
W = [3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3];  M = 7;    % test data

n = numel(W);
sorted = sort(W);
cs = cumsum(sorted);
candidates = cs./sorted+(n-1:-1:0);    % what you get with a = sorted(i)
i = find(candidates>=M, 1, 'last');    
if (numel(i)==0)
    disp('No solution');                % M is too big
else
    a = cs(i)/(M-(n-i))         % from the equation  cs(i)/a + (n-i) = M
    disp(min(W/a,1));           % for confirmation of correctness
    disp(sum(min(W/a,1)));      % for confirmation of correctness
end
```

This returns

```
a = 4.6667

0.6429    0.2143    0.8571    0.2143    1.0000    1.0000    0.4286    1.0000    1.0000    0.6429

 7
```

Comment: Homegrown Tomato's solution is really element. Thank you very much.

Comment: If this solutions works for you, you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it.